# in a C++ OUTLOOK plugin, using the MAPI, is there a difference between attaching a file via the menu or a button vs drag-n-drop

Tags: c++, windows, outlook, mfc, outlook-addin

I'm trying to implement a plug-in for Outlook.  One of the things I do is generate an "event" (I log it) whenever an email has an attachment.  However, while my code works when I attach via a menu or button, it doesn't trigger when I use drag-n-drop to attach the file.  What gives?  I would expect it to be the same code

Comment: You really need to be a lot more specific than that. What exactly does not work? What are the relevant snippets of your code? Are you saying `MailItem.AttachmentAdd` event does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The [MailItem.AttachmentAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.attachmentadd) event is fired when files are dropped onto the Outlook window and attached. It seems the problem is in your code.

Comment: This alone is very helpful.  I'm relatively new to this and quite confused at times

Comment: OK.  I have an Outlook plug-in I'm working on.  In the code whenever a user attaches a file to an e-mail, we log that a file was attached.  When the user then clicks SEND, we log a Send event.  This is what is supposed to happen always.  HOWEVER, while when the user attaches the file by a method OTHER than drag-n-drop, we see the logging for both events, when the user uses drag-n-drop, we only see the attach event, not the send.  I forgot to mention that FSLogix is running on the system

Comment: I wish I could find MSDN documentation on this

Comment: Before posting the answer I've created a new sample Outlook add-in which handles the `AttachmentAdd` event. I can confirm the event is fired when users attach files be dropping them into an inspector window. It seems something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Any chance I may have that sample?  I'd be eternally grateful.  I need to understand what is wrong here